# Get a list of valid users and groups for for a specific component or page

Tags: core-service, workflow, security, user-management, permissions

I am building a custom UI for workflow assignment, and would like to be able to get a list of all users who can see my item in workflow so that I can reassign tasks to them (I don't want to assign a workflow task to a user who can't access the item like the CME does).

I am struggling to find a Core Service method which will allow me to do this. At the moment my only approach is to get a list of all users in the system, and then impersonate them one at a time to see if they can read the object. This seems like a terrible (and very slow) approach, and won't work for groups. Can someone suggest a better way to tackle this problem?

Comment: good luck... :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to extend the Tridion permission API...  for now maybe a less beautiful but faster method would be to persist the user - group - workflow and folder permissions to another data store...

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the same type of feature in my project. 
Here are the steps that I have followed -

First read the all the tasks from that workflow process.
Then read the group involved in that tasks.
After that from Group read the list of users.

Hope this will help you.